# Middle button on Touchpad

Tags: buttons, mouse

I had never seen live any laptop which touchpad block includes a middle mouse button. It always brings only left and right mouse buttons.

So the question is: what can I do to achieve the effect of the middle mouse button?

Side note: I wanted to put:

laptop touchpad/trackpad middle

as tags, but I could not.

Comment: To be honest, I have never seen a mouse with a middle button since 1980 or so.

Comment: @BartGijssens: The middle button is the button you have when you press the mouse wheel

Comment: On my Logitech mouse that only controls the way the scrollwheel behaves (with ticks or without).

Comment: @BartGijssens: I am not speaking about the Hyper-scroll toggling button; When you press the scrollwheel down that is the middle mouse button click.

Comment: I am sorry but I am just descrubing the behhaviour of my mouse  (Loitech m560). It has no "middle button" as you describe it.

Comment: @BartGijssens Sounds like your mouse sucks then.

Comment: lol a mouse with a scroll wheel that cannot behave as 'middle button', the internet never fails to surprise one...

Comment: Middle mouse buttons were very common for older [HP elitebooks](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/96/HP_Elitebook_8770w.png). Incidentally I'm looking to replace mine and this is something I really want...

Answer (score 5):

I've never seen a physical middle click on any laptop but I've seen those implementation:

- Press both left and right click at the same time
- Three-finger tap/click anywhere on the trackpad

My analysis on the lack of physical middle button is that its usage is not that common and thus not worth to use precious space for it. Many, many users do not even use the middle click when using a regular mouse so adding an extra button might throw off many users, plus it would make the other click buttons even smaller.

The most well-known usage of the middle click is to open a link in a new tab, which can also be achieved by pressing `Ctrl` + `Left click` as an alternative.

---

*Subjective opinion:*
I tend to prefer software touch gestures rather than physical buttons (e.g. trackpads on Apple laptops) because you get more trackpad surface and the ability to change gestures and actions through software.
I added the three-finger tap gesture on both of my laptops: on OSX using the powerful and super-useful [BetterTouchTool](http://www.boastr.de/) and on Windows using Synaptics drivers and [some registry editing](http://mikemurko.com/general/3-finger-middle-click/).

Comment: And other well known use of the middle button is also to close tabs, which you forgot to refer.

Comment: If you have CAD applications, it is a sine qua non condition to have a middle mouse button. They are extensively graphic and to support all operations the middle button is essential.

Comment: In some applications, like the the Opera versions before 15, simulating the middle click with both left and right buttons seems not to be a good idea, because there where specific actions associated to the "Left then Right" and "Right then Left" gestures.

Comment: About your links: The BetterTouch tool can not be for me because my laptop is not a Mac and worse, it has not the multi finger touch capabilty. On the other hand, the "3 finger middle click (not 3 middle fingers)" page seems very interesting.

Comment: The middle-mouse button is very useful in many applications. It's often used in 3D-related program (CAD/games) to do important interactions such as rotating the camera. I absolutery did not say that the middle mouse button is useless, I couldn't use my computer without it without heavily changing my habits. I think I'm not that wrong when I say that most users don't need it that much (people just browsing on social networks / watching (cat) videos and pictures, which is what most people do on computers :p)

Comment: @refreshfr the "most users don't need it that much" assumption doesn't quite stand because it's the same on notebooks aimed at professionals.

Answer (score 2):

First I'd like to say that not all laptops lack a middle mouse button. I had a Lenovo Thinkpad laptop with a middle mouse button for the trackpad (picture below from web).

As for how to achieve the effect, you can use AutoHotKey which enables you to write a script to assign the middle mouse button (or any other button/key) to a keyboard key, CapsLock for example.
You will have to write your own script, or search the web for an already written one

[image]